# Critical path algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, algorithms

If I want to compute the shortest path between two points in a directed graph, I can use the Dijkistra algorithm. But what if I want to compute the longest path?

If the weights on the graph are bounded, then I guess I can use Djkstra to the graph with weights $M-c_i$, where $M = \max_i c_i$.

Is this correct? What if the weights are not bound? What can I do then?

Comment: Is the path allowed to visit a node more than once?  Or to cover an edge more than once?

Comment: @hardmath good catch! I was thinking of an acyclic graph. Do you think my method works in this context? Do you know a more elegant algorithm that could detect loops during execution?

Comment: For an undirected graph, any non-uniqueness of paths between two points implies a cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant replace the weights with $M-c_i$ because that favors routes with fewer steps. An example is a graph where there are two ways to go from a to b, a direct route with length 10 and a route via c with length 10+1. You suggest to replace this with a shortest path problem where the choice is between a direct route with length 0 and a route via c with length 0+9. This results in the wrong answer (direct route).

Longest path is an NP-hard problem, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem). For acyclyc graphs you can just replace the lengths $c_i$ with $-c_i$ and use a shortest path algorithm that can deal with negative lengths.

Comment: While we cannot replace the weights with $M-c_i$, any path from a to b in an acyclic graph is unique.  So the only thing to check is if a path exists, i.e. do both nodes belong to the same connected component.

Comment: @hardmath I was super confused about your insistence on undirectedness, but I just saw I made a typo on the Q, it should be directed! Sorry!